# Unable to activate List workflow 2013

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow, workflow-activity

I am unable to activate workflow feature. it is a list workflow which has assign task activity.

This is a approval workflow. but after deployment i am not able to activate it throws the below error.

All the required list is created and target list and task list but it throws error "Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException"

***Microsoft.Workflow.Client.ActivityNotFoundException: The activity named 'WorkflowXaml_20d90204_8608_4c9d_ada7_d9b163b54268' from scope '/SharePoint/default/778c55e4-1ff5-4f28-86b9-87411eaeaa9e/5f962283-5c4a-48e8-8fec-5cdc1916f068' was not found. HTTP headers received from the server - ActivityId: ae7ba2d2-d519-425c-94d9-ebe2d879224e. NodeId: VDDP23G-5536CAF. Scope: /SharePoint/default/778c55e4-1ff5-4f28-86b9-87411eaeaa9e/5f962283-5c4a-48e8-8fec-5cdc1916f068. Client ActivityId : 8976859c-a9bf-107***

Please help if you guys have faced this error while activating list workflow with assign task process as one of the activity.

Answer (score 1):

I see this error so you must follow workflow sharepoint 2013 syntax.
Use transition to stage to goin end of workflow!
And if you can Put your Workflow ScreenShot
Hope this is usefull

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It could possible something to do with that the workflow did not publish before saving your project site as a template.

The "Elements.xml" file, which is packaged within the "wsp" solution file contains 2 "

PropertyName="WSPublishState" Value="3"

Also note that the WSPublishState property is also duplicated within the "MetaInfo" property, so both occurrences should be updated. Then the resulting files need to be re-packaged into the template.

Reference : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/be41f1c5-1dfb-4869-9a52-1c93902bfd91/microsoftworkflowclientactivitynotfoundexception-when-deploying-solution-with-workflow

Comment: where can I find the "MetaInfo" property?